# Cloud9 IDE Themes not switching

Tags: cloud9-ide

I'm having some problems with the cloud 9 IDE. I was trying out the different themes, when suddenly it stopped changing themes properly. I've tried a lot of things, but as it stands, the only part that changes is the editor. The terminal, file tree, and menus are stuck on one theme. Has anyone encountered this problem and found a way to fix it? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Can you paste the browser's error logs when you try changing themes and it doesn't work?

Comment: Thanks everyone. Tim's trick reset the theme, and if I change the theme in the preferences like a-user said the whole thing does indeed change (this skipped my mind before when on the preference tab as I only tried changing the syntax theme). The weird thing is that it when choosing a theme from the View menu it was at first changing the terminal and other stuff as well (I don't know why), but then suddenly stopped, which is why I got confused. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 9):

Try adding the url param `?reset=1` to your workspace url. This will reset your theme (and all Cloud9 settings such as keybindings etc) to default so that you can change it again.

Answer (score 0):

You can change main theme from preferences tab.

Answer (score 0):

Select view -> Themes -> UI themes